# JS to show bytesLoaded of SWF

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash

I want to use Javascript / AJAX to show % loaded of SWF.

The thing is I cannot edit the ActionScript. I have seen this done before...

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: "can not edit the ActionScript" means you do not know how or that you have SWF file that you can not change?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can encapsulate your swf in another one. This other one is only a container, and with this you can measure the percent loaded.

1. You have the original swf
2. You create a container
3. Load the original swf into the new one
4. Show the percent in the container
5. When finished loading, hide percent text and show original swf